# É possível comparar uma coluna de um select no mesmo select?

Tags: mysql

sou novo aqui e não encontrei respostas que sanasse minha dúvida no MySQL.

Tenho um select que retorna uma coluna de valores e eu queria comprar essa coluna com outra coluna do mesmo select sem ter que reescrever o select por exemplo:

--Criando a tabela

Create Table Exemplo (Chave Primary Key Not null Unique, Valor1 Varchar(10), Valor2 Varchar(10))
Insert into Exemplo (Chave, Valor1,Valor2) Values (,15,6)
Insert into Exemplo (Chave, Valor1,Valor2) Values (,10,10)
Insert into Exemplo (Chave, Valor1,Valor2) Values (,50,1)
Insert into Exemplo (Chave, Valor1,Valor2) Values (,18,11)

--Fazendo o Select

Select Chave, Valor1, Valor2, (Valor2 + 10) 'NovoValor', case when (Valor2+10)>Valor1 then (valor2+10) else Valor1 end 'MaiorValor' from Exemplo

--Dúvida: Como faço para que esse select retorne o resultado da coluna 'MaiorValor' sem ter que usar o case when, pois essa expressão 'Valor2+10' é um select enorme no meu banco de dados e ter que repetí-lo deixa o select muito maior.

Answer (score -2):

Opa, se você precisa realizar comparações baseada em duas colunas, não vejo muitas alternativas. Uma alternativa é transferir essa lógica para a aplicação que persiste esse dado na base.

Comment: 1 faça uma view , 2 faça um subselect , select a,b,c from (select .........) mas qual o seu problema fazer a conta ou reduzir o tamanho do select ?

Comment: A ideia de diminuir o tamanha do select seria para melhor compreensão dos outros programadores e pelo fato do Banco de Dados que eu consulto ser muito grande (queria diminuir o tempo de execução da consulta) em outras palavras Otimizá-lo

Comment: Diminuir o tempo de execução parte de alguns princípios, não sou DBA mas verifique o plano de execução da sua query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html#:~:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20statements.&text=That%20is%2C%20MySQL%20explains%20how,joined%20and%20in%20which%20order.

Evite full scans e verifique indexação de suas tabelas.